# Class implements interface, but the arguments to a method of a member variable have no type?

Tags: typescript

So let's just look at my code. It's not very well described.

This is interface:

```
interface IModel<T = any> {
  effects: {
    [key: string]: (getState: () => T) => void;
  };
}

interface IState {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

This is wrong, but I don't know why:

```
class Model implements IModel<IState> {
  effects = {
    getName: (getState) => {
      const { /** Here, Ts has no smart tips */ } = getState();
    }
  };
}
```

Need me to add type, just can have tips:

```
class Model implements IModel<IState> {
  effects = {
    getName: (getState: () => IState) => { // add type
      const { /** Yes, have 'name' and 'age' */ } = getState();
    }
  };
}
```

But, I think the latter approach is a bit verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this. Check https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373 for updates.