# TypeScript 'number' not assignable to 0 | 10 | 20 even if number is 0

Tags: javascript, typescript

If you try my snippet below on [the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPlan%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20plan%3A%200%20%7C%2010%20%7C%2020%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20IPlan%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20plan%3A%200%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20also%20fine%0D%0Alet%20commands%3A%20IPlan%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20plan%3A%2010%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20not%20fine%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20AbstractThing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20commands%3F%3A%20IPlan%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Thing%20extends%20AbstractThing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20line%20has%20the%20error%0D%0A%20%20commands%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20plan%3A%2010%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D) it shows an error on line 24.

I realize it can be fixed by explictly casting commands to `<IPlan[]>` again, but why is this necessary?

```
Property 'commands' in type 'Thing' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'AbstractThing'.
  Type '{ plan: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IPlan[]'.
    Type '{ plan: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IPlan'.
      Types of property 'plan' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 10 | 20'.
(property) Thing.commands: { plan: number; }[]
```

Here's the snippet:

```
interface IPlan {
  plan: 0 | 10 | 20;
}

// fine
let obj: IPlan = {
  plan: 0
};

// also fine
let commands: IPlan[] = [
  {
    plan: 10
  }
];

// not fine
abstract class AbstractThing {
  commands?: IPlan[];
}

class Thing extends AbstractThing {
  // this line has the error
  commands = [
    {
      plan: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `plan: 10 as 10` would work!

Comment: There's something odd in the way you assign the variable inside `Thing`, since you are assigning it out of a method. You should try putting the assignation inside a constructor, it would fix the error

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667)... they [tried and failed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207) to fix this [multiple times](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10610) before; for now there is just no contextual typing for members of `extends` classes.  A good comment about this is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570#issuecomment-296860943).

Comment: @jcalz your comment is the most correct explanation as to why it doesn't work. If you could make it an answer I would be happy to accept it as the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class implements interface, but the arguments to a method of a member variable have no type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488807/class-implements-interface-but-the-arguments-to-a-method-of-a-member-variable-h/55489193#55489193)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically inferring types from overridden interfaces in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596117/automatically-inferring-types-from-overridden-interfaces-in-typescript/44620915#44620915)

Comment: A bit late, but a better solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577557/declare-interface-type-1-2-why-cannot-assign-type-1-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667) in which properties (and methods, mentioned in a [different issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373)) are not [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) or influenced in any way by the analogous properties of a base class or implemented interface.  There is, of course, a *check* that the properties match, but this happens *after* normal type inference happens.  So in the following code:

```
class Foo {
  x = "hello";
}

interface Interface {
  x: "hello" | "goodbye";
}

class Bar implements Interface {
  x = "hello"; // error!
}

class Base {
  x: "hello" | "goodbye" = "hello";
}
class Baz extends Base {
  x = "hello"; // error!
}
```

The inference for property `x` is the same in `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`.  The `"hello"` is initially interpreted as a string literal, but when it is assigned to the `x` property, it is [widened to `string` according to the rule](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676):

> - The type inferred for a ... non-readonly property with an initializer and no type annotation is the widened literal type of the initializer.

This is fine for `Foo`, but causes an error in `Bar` and `Baz`, since `string` does not match the `implements` or `extends` constraints.  Yuck!  Pretty much everyone agrees when they see this that it shouldn't be this way.  Of course the implemented interface or extended class should affect how property inference takes place.

Well, they [tried and failed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207) to fix this [multiple times](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10610) before; for now it just doesn't happen.  Apparently the changes ended up causing more trouble than they resolved.  A good comment about the issues involved is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570#issuecomment-296860943).

I hope there will one day be some sort of update that eases this pain point.  For now, you're just going to have to use type annotations or other type hints to let the compiler know what to do.  So, in the `Bar` and `Baz` examples, you could do this:

```
class Bar implements Interface {
  x: Interface['x'] = "hello"; // okay, "hello" | "goodbye"
}
```

In `Bar`, we've used an explicit type annotation to make `Bar["x"]` exactly match `Interface["x"]` (meaning that you could change `x` later to be `"goodbye"` instead of `"hello"`).  This is often appropriate where you're not trying to specialize the property, but just make it compatible.  And:

```
class Baz extends Base {
  readonly x = "hello"; // okay, readonly narrows to "hello" only
}
```

In `Baz`, we've used `readonly` to hint to the compiler to keep `x` as narrow as possible, so `x` can only be `"hello"`.  It is narrower than `Base["x"]`.  This is often appropriate when you treat the property as a [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) to distinguish one subtype from another.

Hopefully one of those works for you.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but using the abstract class makes it think that the definition of `plan` is `number` instead of the specific values you listed.

These two "workarounds" will help ensure the correct type is used though

```js
class Thing extends AbstractThing {
  commands = [
    {
      plan: 10
    }
  ] as IPlan[]
}
```

and

```js
class Thing extends AbstractThing {
  commands: IPlan[] = [
    {
      plan: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "strongly" specifying the type like this IS the recommended approach from what I've seen. I would go with this.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, it's likely that TypeScript isn't such good at interferring the type if the variable is defined out of a method.

To fix the problem, you should just move the declaration inside the constructor, as you can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPlan%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20plan%3A%200%20%7C%2010%20%7C%2020%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20IPlan%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20plan%3A%200%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20also%20fine%0D%0Alet%20commands%3A%20IPlan%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20plan%3A%2010%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20not%20fine%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20AbstractThing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20commands%3F%3A%20IPlan%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Thing%20extends%20AbstractThing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20line%20has%20the%20error%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.commands%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20plan%3A%2010%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D):

```
class Thing extends AbstractThing {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.commands = [
      {
        plan: 10
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

But this is probably just a bug in the engine

Answer (score 0):

In your interface definition you constrain the type of the plan property to be one of the values 0, 10, 20. But when you assign the commands property in the class:

```
commands = [
  {
    plan: 10
  }
]
```

The `plan` property has type `number`. Even though you've set it to 10, the *type* is not constrained in any way, so since it's less restrictive than the type of `plan` in the interface the compiler rejects it.

You could fix this a couple of ways, but the easiest is to cast the object to cast the object to the interface:

```
commands = [
  (<IPlan>{
    plan: 10
  })
]
```

Remember types (more-or-less) use set logic. Imagine that you are the type-checker programmer and you see the literal expression

```
{
  plan: 10,
}
```

There are several ways to interpret this. Here are just two for our purposes:

- There's an object, and it has a plan, attribute, and the only permissible value is 10.
- There's an object, and it has a plan, attribute, and it is a number.

There's all sorts of other considerations here (null? other keys?) but the compiler just isn't smart enough to deduce that because you used the literal '10' the type is compatible with the interface. Plus the value could change at run-time, etc.