# Declare interface {type: 1 | 2}, why cannot assign { type: 1 } to it

Tags: typescript

```
interface Question {
    type: 1 | 2
}

const obj = { type: 1 };
let question: Question;
question = obj; // not work
```

the error is:

> Type '{ type: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Question'.   Types
>   of property 'type' are incompatible.
>       Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 2'.

why? I used `Question` as a React props type checker, but I cannot pass the `obj` as a props to the component.

Comment: I tried it on https://typescript-play.js.org, and all works as expected.

Comment: Actually that sample works as expetcted: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: I'm so sorry,  I had changed my code, now it will throw this error. @MaximeLafarie @ Titian Cernicova-Dragomir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of type widening. In `{ type: 1 }`, `type` is inferred to be a `number` and not a constant `1`. If you want to prevent this from happening you can define it as a constant by adding `as const`:

```
interface Question {
    type: 1 | 2
}

const obj = { type: 1 as const }; // "as const" will prevent type widening here
let question: Question;
question = obj;
```